# getting property names at compile time without using magic string, similar to T4MVC concept

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, metadata

Sometimes, I need to get the string equivalent of a property name or expression. Most of the time this is for some serialization or ORM-mappings.  The use is irrelevant.  Instead of typing the string as a "magic string", e.g

```
var sPropertyName = "PropertyId";
```

I use reflection, so that if it changes, it is automatically updated. Example:

```
    public void test()
    {
         var sPropertyName = GetPropertyName<Property>(x => x.PropertyId);
    }



    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
    {

        return (PropertyInfo)GetMemberInfoBySelector(selector);


    }

    public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfoBySelector(Expression selector)
    {
        Expression body = selector;
        if (body is LambdaExpression)
        {
            body = ((LambdaExpression)body).Body;
        }
        switch (body.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Call:
                return (((System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)body).Method);
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                return ((PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)body).Member);
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
                {
                    UnaryExpression unaryExp = (UnaryExpression)body;
                    var op = unaryExp.Operand;
                    System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression memberExp = (MemberExpression)op;
                    return memberExp.Member;

                }
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot retrieve member info from selector!");
        }


    }
```

Sometimes, this is called quite often for batch-processing, or similar processing.  I find it a waste that this resorts to reflection, when the value can actually be a constant.  In cases where it is used a lot, this can slow things down quite a bit.

I know there exists a tool for ASP.Net MVC - [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) which scans the files and creates static classes with the property names.

In this case, something ideal would be where I could just use say

```
var sPropertyName = GeneratedMetaData.MyNamespace.Property.PropertyId
```

Is this somehow possible?  I know I can store these constants myself on app start, but wanted to know if there is something automatic like T4MVC is.

Or maybe other approaches which does the same thing?